# Error during installation of pyopencl in mac os

Tags: python, tensorflow, pyopencl

```
  Building wheels for collected packages: pyopencl
  Building wheel for pyopencl (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/fg/f0d_bx3s0gn4rqx67twbd2y80000gn/T/pip-install-6yfzysq9/pyopencl/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/fg/f0d_bx3s0gn4rqx67twbd2y80000gn/T/pip-install-6yfzysq9/pyopencl/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/fg/f0d_bx3s0gn4rqx67twbd2y80000gn/T/pip-wheel-a9v8vv35
       cwd: /private/var/folders/fg/f0d_bx3s0gn4rqx67twbd2y80000gn/T/pip-install-6yfzysq9/pyopencl/
  Complete output (117 lines):
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Pybind11 is not installed.
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Very likely, the build process after this message will fail.

  Simply press Ctrl+C and type
  python -m pip install pybind11
  to fix this. If you don't, the build will continue
  in a few seconds.

  [1] https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Continuing in 1 seconds...    
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Mako is not installed.
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  That is not a problem, as most of PyOpenCL will be just fine
  without it. Some higher-level parts of pyopencl (such as
  pyopencl.reduction) will not function without the templating engine
  Mako [1] being installed. If you would like this functionality to
  work, you might want to install Mako after you finish
  installing PyOpenCL.

  Simply type
  python -m pip install mako
  either now or after the installation completes to fix this.

  [1] http://www.makotemplates.org/
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Hit Ctrl-C now if you'd like to think about the situation.
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Continuing in 1 seconds...   
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
  copying pyopencl/algorithm.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
  copying pyopencl/clmath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
  copying pyopencl/version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
  copying pyopencl/capture_call.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
  copying pyopencl/reduction.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
  copying pyopencl/tools.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
  copying pyopencl/elementwise.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
  copying pyopencl/cache.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
  copying pyopencl/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
  copying pyopencl/cltypes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
  copying pyopencl/invoker.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
  copying pyopencl/ipython_ext.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
  copying pyopencl/scan.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
  copying pyopencl/_cluda.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
  copying pyopencl/_mymako.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
  copying pyopencl/array.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
  copying pyopencl/bitonic_sort.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
  copying pyopencl/bitonic_sort_templates.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
  copying pyopencl/_buffers.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
  copying pyopencl/clrandom.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/compyte
  copying pyopencl/compyte/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/compyte
  copying pyopencl/compyte/dtypes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/compyte
  copying pyopencl/compyte/array.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/compyte
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/characterize
  copying pyopencl/characterize/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/characterize
  copying pyopencl/characterize/performance.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/characterize
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/compyte/ndarray
  copying pyopencl/compyte/ndarray/gen_reduction.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/compyte/ndarray
  copying pyopencl/compyte/ndarray/test_gpu_elemwise.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/compyte/ndarray
  copying pyopencl/compyte/ndarray/setup_opencl.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/compyte/ndarray
  copying pyopencl/compyte/ndarray/gen_elemwise.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/compyte/ndarray
  copying pyopencl/compyte/ndarray/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/compyte/ndarray
  copying pyopencl/compyte/ndarray/test_gpu_ndarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/compyte/ndarray
  running egg_info
  writing pyopencl.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to pyopencl.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to pyopencl.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing top-level names to pyopencl.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'pyopencl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no files found matching '*.h'
  warning: no files found matching 'doc/_static/*.css'
  warning: no files found matching 'doc/_templates/*.html'
  warning: no files found matching '*.py.in'
  writing manifest file 'pyopencl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/cl
  copying pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-airy.cl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/cl
  copying pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-bessel-j-complex.cl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/cl
  copying pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-bessel-j.cl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/cl
  copying pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-bessel-y.cl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/cl
  copying pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-complex.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/cl
  copying pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-eval-tbl.cl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/cl
  copying pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-hankel-complex.cl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/cl
  copying pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-ranluxcl.cl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/cl
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-random123
  copying pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-random123/array.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-random123
  copying pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-random123/openclfeatures.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-random123
  copying pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-random123/philox.cl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-random123
  copying pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-random123/threefry.cl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-random123
  running build_ext
  creating var
  creating var/folders
  creating var/folders/fg
  creating var/folders/fg/f0d_bx3s0gn4rqx67twbd2y80000gn
  creating var/folders/fg/f0d_bx3s0gn4rqx67twbd2y80000gn/T
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -fwrapv -Wall -O3 -DNDEBUG -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c /var/folders/fg/f0d_bx3s0gn4rqx67twbd2y80000gn/T/tmphh9gba3s.cpp -o var/folders/fg/f0d_bx3s0gn4rqx67twbd2y80000gn/T/tmphh9gba3s.o -std=gnu++14
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -fwrapv -Wall -O3 -DNDEBUG -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c /var/folders/fg/f0d_bx3s0gn4rqx67twbd2y80000gn/T/tmpi6ghg0z3.cpp -o var/folders/fg/f0d_bx3s0gn4rqx67twbd2y80000gn/T/tmpi6ghg0z3.o -fvisibility=hidden
  building 'pyopencl._cl' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -fwrapv -Wall -O3 -DNDEBUG -DPYGPU_PACKAGE=pyopencl -DPYGPU_PYOPENCL=1 -Ipybind11/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I/Users/proshore/Library/Python/3.7/include/python3.7m -I/Users/proshore/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c src/wrap_constants.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src/wrap_constants.o -fvisibility=hidden -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -DVERSION_INFO="2019.1.2" -std=gnu++14 -fvisibility=hidden
  In file included from src/wrap_constants.cpp:30:
  In file included from src/wrap_cl.hpp:86:
  src/wrap_helpers.hpp:31:10: fatal error: 'pybind11/pybind11.h' file not found
  #include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyopencl
  Running setup.py clean for pyopencl
Failed to build pyopencl
Installing collected packages: pyopencl
    Running setup.py install for pyopencl ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/fg/f0d_bx3s0gn4rqx67twbd2y80000gn/T/pip-install-6yfzysq9/pyopencl/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/fg/f0d_bx3s0gn4rqx67twbd2y80000gn/T/pip-install-6yfzysq9/pyopencl/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/fg/f0d_bx3s0gn4rqx67twbd2y80000gn/T/pip-record-etli11dw/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pyopencl
         cwd: /private/var/folders/fg/f0d_bx3s0gn4rqx67twbd2y80000gn/T/pip-install-6yfzysq9/pyopencl/
    Complete output (112 lines):
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Pybind11 is not installed.
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Very likely, the build process after this message will fail.

    Simply press Ctrl+C and type
    python -m pip install pybind11
    to fix this. If you don't, the build will continue
    in a few seconds.

    [1] https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Continuing in 1 seconds...    
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Mako is not installed.
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    That is not a problem, as most of PyOpenCL will be just fine
    without it. Some higher-level parts of pyopencl (such as
    pyopencl.reduction) will not function without the templating engine
    Mako [1] being installed. If you would like this functionality to
    work, you might want to install Mako after you finish
    installing PyOpenCL.

    Simply type
    python -m pip install mako
    either now or after the installation completes to fix this.

    [1] http://www.makotemplates.org/
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Hit Ctrl-C now if you'd like to think about the situation.
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Continuing in 1 seconds...   
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
    copying pyopencl/algorithm.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
    copying pyopencl/clmath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
    copying pyopencl/version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
    copying pyopencl/capture_call.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
    copying pyopencl/reduction.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
    copying pyopencl/tools.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
    copying pyopencl/elementwise.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
    copying pyopencl/cache.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
    copying pyopencl/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
    copying pyopencl/cltypes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
    copying pyopencl/invoker.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
    copying pyopencl/ipython_ext.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
    copying pyopencl/scan.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
    copying pyopencl/_cluda.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
    copying pyopencl/_mymako.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
    copying pyopencl/array.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
    copying pyopencl/bitonic_sort.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
    copying pyopencl/bitonic_sort_templates.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
    copying pyopencl/_buffers.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
    copying pyopencl/clrandom.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/compyte
    copying pyopencl/compyte/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/compyte
    copying pyopencl/compyte/dtypes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/compyte
    copying pyopencl/compyte/array.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/compyte
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/characterize
    copying pyopencl/characterize/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/characterize
    copying pyopencl/characterize/performance.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/characterize
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/compyte/ndarray
    copying pyopencl/compyte/ndarray/gen_reduction.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/compyte/ndarray
    copying pyopencl/compyte/ndarray/test_gpu_elemwise.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/compyte/ndarray
    copying pyopencl/compyte/ndarray/setup_opencl.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/compyte/ndarray
    copying pyopencl/compyte/ndarray/gen_elemwise.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/compyte/ndarray
    copying pyopencl/compyte/ndarray/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/compyte/ndarray
    copying pyopencl/compyte/ndarray/test_gpu_ndarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/compyte/ndarray
    running egg_info
    writing pyopencl.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pyopencl.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to pyopencl.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing top-level names to pyopencl.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'pyopencl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h'
    warning: no files found matching 'doc/_static/*.css'
    warning: no files found matching 'doc/_templates/*.html'
    warning: no files found matching '*.py.in'
    writing manifest file 'pyopencl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/cl
    copying pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-airy.cl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/cl
    copying pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-bessel-j-complex.cl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/cl
    copying pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-bessel-j.cl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/cl
    copying pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-bessel-y.cl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/cl
    copying pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-complex.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/cl
    copying pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-eval-tbl.cl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/cl
    copying pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-hankel-complex.cl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/cl
    copying pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-ranluxcl.cl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/cl
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-random123
    copying pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-random123/array.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-random123
    copying pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-random123/openclfeatures.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-random123
    copying pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-random123/philox.cl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-random123
    copying pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-random123/threefry.cl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/pyopencl/cl/pyopencl-random123
    running build_ext
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -fwrapv -Wall -O3 -DNDEBUG -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c /var/folders/fg/f0d_bx3s0gn4rqx67twbd2y80000gn/T/tmpp86czk27.cpp -o var/folders/fg/f0d_bx3s0gn4rqx67twbd2y80000gn/T/tmpp86czk27.o -std=gnu++14
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -fwrapv -Wall -O3 -DNDEBUG -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c /var/folders/fg/f0d_bx3s0gn4rqx67twbd2y80000gn/T/tmperpl60nv.cpp -o var/folders/fg/f0d_bx3s0gn4rqx67twbd2y80000gn/T/tmperpl60nv.o -fvisibility=hidden
    building 'pyopencl._cl' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -fwrapv -Wall -O3 -DNDEBUG -DPYGPU_PACKAGE=pyopencl -DPYGPU_PYOPENCL=1 -Ipybind11/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I/Users/proshore/Library/Python/3.7/include/python3.7m -I/Users/proshore/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c src/wrap_constants.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src/wrap_constants.o -fvisibility=hidden -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -DVERSION_INFO="2019.1.2" -std=gnu++14 -fvisibility=hidden
    In file included from src/wrap_constants.cpp:30:
    In file included from src/wrap_cl.hpp:86:
    src/wrap_helpers.hpp:31:10: fatal error: 'pybind11/pybind11.h' file not found
    #include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/fg/f0d_bx3s0gn4rqx67twbd2y80000gn/T/pip-install-6yfzysq9/pyopencl/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/fg/f0d_bx3s0gn4rqx67twbd2y80000gn/T/pip-install-6yfzysq9/pyopencl/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/fg/f0d_bx3s0gn4rqx67twbd2y80000gn/T/pip-record-etli11dw/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pyopencl Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Pybind11 is not installed.

Install it using `pip install pybind11`